# How to configure a non-default WinRM port? error indicates an unknown GP parameter

Tags: windows-services, event-log, winrm

I want to set the WinRM **listening port to 443**

Trying on Windows Server 2012 and 2016

when I run:

```
Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\listener\listener*\Port -Value 443
```

I get:

> Set-Item : WS-Management does not allow changes to a listener created automatically by the group policy. The policy "**Allow Auto Configuration of listeners on WinRm service**" would need to be set to "Not Configured" in order to create a new listener for same Address and Transport or to modify an already existing listener.

but when I go to: `Computer Configuration ->Administrative Templates ->Windows Components ->Windows Remote Management(WinRM) ->WinRM Service`. The problem is that there is no policy called **Allow Auto Configuration of listeners on WinRm service**.

How do I break this circle?

Answer (score 0):

"Allow Auto Configuration of listeners on WinRm service" has been unhelpfully renamed to "Allow remote server management through WinRM".

I got that from this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/797535/enter-pssession-on-localhost-is-failing

I worked around a similar issue by creating a Group Policy and setting it to disabled.  That allowed me to delete the listener and not get that error.

Hope this helps.